# Can I access Facebook Ad Billing data through an API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

/business.facebook.com/ads/manager/billing/transactions/

Thats the url id like to pull data from. I looked at all the API's, but none of them seem to offer up this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{business_id}/business_invoices`

Answer (score 0):

YES YOU CAN USIG FACEBOOK MARKETING API Marketing APIs are a collection of Graph API endpoints that can be used to help you advertise on Facebook. To get started with advertising on Facebook, we recommend you learn about Facebook's Ad Campaign Structure, to understand the objects you're working with and how they relate to each other.
CHECK THIS OUT
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/